# How to change one character into another in R

Tags: r

i want to make a function where, if an argument includes "A", "T", "G", "C" n numbers of times and it could replace T into U and gives back all the changed argument, then what should be the appropriate way to code this in R?
set of code which i have made or i want to use for y personal preference is=

````
    ``` r
data=c("A","T","G","C")

change<-function(compound)
+ {
+     molecules<-unlist(strsplit(compound,""))
+     
+     
+     gsub("T","U",string)
+ }
change("ATGC")
Error in gsub("T", "U", string) : object 'string' not found
#> Error: <text>:9:3: unexpected '}'
#> 8: +     gsub("T","U",string)
#> 9: + }
#>      ^
```
````

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Argument would be like change("AAAATTTTGGGGCCCCC")
and it should give an output=AAAAUUUUGGGGCCCC

Please help me with this problem.
Thank you

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `gsub("T", "U", string)` ?

Comment: Or `chartr("T", "U", x)`

Comment: ``` r
data=c("A","T","G","C")

change<-function(compound)
+ {
+     molecules<-unlist(strsplit(compound,""))
+     
+     
+     gsub("T","U",string)
+ }
change("ATGC")
Error in gsub("T", "U", string) : object 'string' not found
Called from: gsub("T", "U", string)
#> Error: <text>:9:3: unexpected '}'
#> 8: +     gsub("T","U",string)
#> 9: + }
#>      ^
```

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
it os showing me error with this. @G5W

Comment: Please edit your original question. Comment section is not designed to handle code chunks.

Comment: @Jaap thank you for this but it does not give me the same number of characters as my argument. also i want output in AUUUUGGCCC manner not in "A","U","G","C" manner

Comment: Please check the output of `chartr("T", "U", "AAAATTTTGGGGCCCCC")` or `gsub("T", "U", "AAAATTTTGGGGCCCCC")`. Both give the desired output: `"AAAAUUUUGGGGCCCCC"`.

Comment: @MayankRajput There might be an inconcsistency in your post.  The more complete example says `change("AAAATTTTGGGGCCCCC")` (ie, there's a single element, consisting of multiple characters).  The other example says `c("A","T","G","C")` (ie, multiple elements, consisting of a single character).

Comment: @Jaap what if i want to make a function for this, i dont want to use chartr or gsub directly

Comment: Why would you like to make a new function when `gsub` and `chartr` are ready available?

Comment: @wibeasley no sir i mean my argument could contain n number times A or T or G or C but it give us  back exact number of arguments with the replacement of T with U

Comment: @Jaap thank you sir i will try to accommodate this in the further steps, i'll ask here if i would stuck in future.

Comment: @Jaap sir, what if i want to change more character for example A to U, T to A, G to C and C to G in a single step then what should i do.

Comment: just adapt the `chartr`-example to `chartr("ATGC", "UACG", "AAAATTTTGGGGCCCCC")`